# Optional URL segments in NGINX

Tags: nginx, regex, proxypass

I need to proxy pass multiple segments further to another server, there can be up two 5 segments.

What nginx needs to match

- example.com/somehash
- example.com/somehash/segment1
- example.com/somehash/segment1/segment2
- example.com/somehash/segment1/segment2/segment3
- example.com/somehash/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4
- example.com/somehash/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4/segment5

Right now, code below, matches only

- example.com/somehash
- example.com/somehash/segment1

For this we have this block of code:

```
location ~* ^/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ {
  proxy_pass http://@tds/direct/$1?$args;
  proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
  proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $server_name;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_redirect off;
}

location ~* ^/([a-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9\-\_\[\]\{\}\.]+)/?$ {
  proxy_pass http://@tds/direct/$1/$2?$args;
  proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
  proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $server_name;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

But now, there can be up to 5 segments, one of solution is basically add 4 more locations so for example, for 5 segments location would look something like this:

```
location ~* ^/([a-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9\-\_\[\]\{\}\.]+)/([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9\-\_\[\]\{\}\.]+)/([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9\-\_\[\]\{\}\.]+)/([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9\-\_\[\]\{\}\.]+)/([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9\-\_\[\]\{\}\.]+)/?$ {
  proxy_pass http://@tds/direct/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5?$args;
  proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
  proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $server_name;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

But that really looks like a crappy solution, and considering the link can also look like
example.com/somehash/landing/5/segment1/segment2/segment3/segment4/segment5

This is even a crappier solution because with this approach, there will be around 12 locations.

Proxy passing segments to another server will look exactly the same way as it looks with one segment, so with 5 segments it would looke something like this
**@tds/direct/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6** (where $1 is 'somehash' and 2 to 6 are optional segments)

Is there a proper way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with simple `location`?

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://@tds/direct/;
  proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

It will proxy request `http://example.com/hash/a/b/c?a=1` to `http://@tds/direct/hash/a/b/c?a=1` for any URI.

See http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

> If the `proxy_pass` directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive

P.S. There is no need to use `proxy_set_header` for `$http_` variables. They are passed by default. Also `X-Real-IP` and `X-Forwarded-For` are redundant.

Comment: I believe this will conflict with some other routes we have, for example we have a route for @tds/first_id/two_id that proxy passes to different link, althrough perhaps that route should be renamed. And is there a way I can limit number of segments to 5 at most with this approach?

Comment: Add location blocks for exceptions. `location /first_id { ... }`

Comment: You will parse URI in your application anyway. Check number of segments there. It would be simpler and cleaner.

Comment: X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded-For were done for a purpose by the way, we needed to pass real user IP and with proxy_pass, If I recall correctly, the server IP that proxy passed request was passed instead.

Anyway, thanks for your help. I will check with your answer shortly.

Comment: `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for` contains `$remote_addr`, so you will have it in `X-Forwarder-For` header. But it's just minor note.

Comment: Thanks! Seem to work just fine for my task. Cant believe its that simple.